# How can I call a global jquery function within document.ready. It generate TypeError: $.myfunction is not a function

Tags: jquery, function, exception, global, typeerror

When I try to define a **global function** ( as I know it and I may be wrong, correct me if I am wrong ) I am unable to call the function within **document.ready()**. This throws an uncaught error `TypeError: $.myfunction is not a function` Is this due to scope issue or something else? What should I do instead to make it work?

```
 (function( $ ){
     $.fn.myfunction = function() {
      alert('hello world');
      return this;
     }; 
 })( jQuery );

 $( document ).ready(function() {
     console.log( "ready!" );
     $.myfunction();
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a selector before calling the function,

```
 $( document ).ready(function() {
 console.log( "ready!" );
 $(this).myfunction();
 });
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ZBXAu/3/)

Answer (score 1):

There is two things you need to know.

`fn` properties are jQuery Object prototype function, which mean that you can't use functions declare as prototype without a jQuery object.

To create a jQuery object you need to call `$`. So `$('').myFunction()` would work.

If you want to use it like that (`$.myFunction();`), you need to assign a function to the jQuery Object Declaration itself, not its prototype. So that would work :

```
$.myFunction = function(){...};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. One of these days, I will delve into the depths of object prototypes for sure.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a selector why not use a normal function instead?

```
var myfunction = function() {
      alert('hello world');
      return this;
     }

$( document ).ready(function() {
     console.log( "ready!" );
     myfunction();
 });
```

Note: `$.fn.myfunction` will not make your function available in the whole project.